# Downloading Captcha And Posting Captcha Value to web directories

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a web directory submission tool which will submit to many phpld directories.Some of the web directories have Captcha for security purpose.How can i
download these captcha images to my desktop application.

I managed to get the URL of Catpcha image.But when i try to fetch that catpcha the 
value changes. How do I get rid off this.

For Example  **http://www.sportleisurenews.com/links/submit.php** .
Please help me to download this captcha and posting the value straight away from it.

Comment: Do u need the captcha in that fashion or what

Comment: The whole point of Captcha is to prevent automatic posting.  It would be kind of missing the point to write a tool specifically to help get around that.  Even assuming your purposes are legitimate, SO responses tend to be high in Google rankings, so that would mean almost anyone else (not as pure as you, obviously) would then also have that knowledge...

Comment: Thnks for being so generous.I got what you sayinh.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use selenium for this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.........

It breaks the real purpose of Captchas..  To stop applications like you are planning build.

Comment: I think you are right.But m not trying to break catpcha.I want to Download that captcha ,then I will manually enter the captcha value and then i post it as anyone does in Web Browser.

If am still going wrong,let me know.I can drop the plan going ahead.Thanks

Comment: The captcha image will change for every request. So downloading and then submitting again may nto work. One option is to have a web browser control, load this webpage and fill out the form fields programatically and then wait for the user to enter captcha and then submit the form.